# How to solve error loading KeypressDelete.ogg, KeypressReturn.ogg?

Tags: java, emulation

I am learning Android from one of the examples in a book (Android Programming - The Big Nerd Ranch Guide) and I am following their code verbatim. Very simple code, well at least I thought...Below is the image of my emulator and most, if not all the code, with the exception of the layout files.

My emulator is using API Level 18 android 4.3.1 cpu ARM. When I click on a crime from the list, I am suppose to see a log stating I clicked on crime #x but I don't see it. Instead I see SoundPool tag with error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg and 4 other similar errors like error loading KeypressReturn.ogg.

I scoured the internet and on stack overflow for a solution for hours. All I can find is "ignore it" or "turn off the settings", which I don't know how but I don't want to turn it off. I want to solve it and move on with this example so I can learn. Would anyone know of this error and can help me solve it, please? I appreciate it.

[image]

Here are part of the code:

```
public class Crime 
{    
    private UUID mId;
    private String mTitle;
    private Date mDate;
    private boolean mSolved;

    public Crime() 
    {
        // Generate unique identifier
        mId = UUID.randomUUID();
        mDate = new Date();
    }

    public String getTitle() 
    {
        return mTitle;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) 
    {
        mTitle = title;
    }

    public UUID getId() 
    {
        return mId;
    }

    public Date getDate() 
    {
        return mDate;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) 
    {
        mDate = date;
    }

    public boolean isSolved() 
    {
        return mSolved;
    }

    public void setSolved(boolean solved) 
    {
        mSolved = solved;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() 
    {
        return mTitle;
    }
}

public class CrimeLab 
{
    private ArrayList<Crime> mCrimes;
    private static CrimeLab sCrimeLab;
    private Context mAppContext;

    private CrimeLab(Context appContext) 
    {
        mAppContext = appContext;
        mCrimes = new ArrayList<Crime>();

        // Mock Crime objects
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) 
        {
            Crime c = new Crime();

            c.setTitle("Crime #" + i);
            c.setSolved(i % 2 == 0); // Every other one
            mCrimes.add(c);
        }
    }

    public static CrimeLab get(Context c) 
    {
        if (sCrimeLab == null)
        {
            sCrimeLab = new CrimeLab(c.getApplicationContext());
        }

        return sCrimeLab;
    }

    public ArrayList<Crime> getCrimes() 
    {
        return mCrimes;
    }

    public Crime getCrime(UUID id) 
    {
        for (Crime c : mCrimes) 
        {
            if (c.getId().equals(id))
                return c;
        }

        return null;
    }
}

package com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent;

import java.util.ArrayList;  
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class CrimeListFragment extends ListFragment 
{
    private static final String TAG = "CrimeListFragment";    
    private ArrayList<Crime> mCrimes;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getActivity().setTitle(R.string.crimes_title);
        mCrimes = CrimeLab.get(getActivity()).getCrimes();

        ArrayAdapter<Crime> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Crime>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mCrimes);

        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) 
    {
        Crime c = (Crime) (getListAdapter()).getItem(position);

        Log.d(TAG, c.getTitle() + " was clicked");
    }
}
```